# in Yii's criteria how to select none PK column only

Tags: php, yii

Yii is selecting the PK when ever I choose a column to select but when I set the select to false it works correctly ...
how can I disable `selecting the PK column by default`

ie .

```
 $criteria->with = array(
        'provider' => array(
            'with' => array(
                'provider_offers' => array(
                    'select' => 'provider_id',// here it select the 'id' with the provider_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will always be selected(needed for relations when u access another model fields). If u r using widget like CGridView or something else try CSqlDataProvider.